# How to rename a vbproject with code VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying new stuff on Excel, among which is file manipulation.
I am trying to change the name of a project within a new file I've just created

I tried this code :

```
Workbooks("Book1").VBProject.Name = "tototot"
```

but it doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Your code works for me - do you have trusted access to the VBA Project set in your trust center settings?

Comment: Yes, that was that. It worked after I ticked the box "trust access to the vba project object...". Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name="testmodel"`

Comment: Thanks, it looked promising, but it didn't work, the name of the project is still VBAProject :/

Comment: after I ticked the box "trust acces to the vba project..." it works fine. TY

Comment: Sure, I did add to check the permissions, then I took it away, I thought it might open up network permission connotations :)  glad you've sorted it.